# How to Push a URL to Open in Browser Using Parse

Tags: android, url, parse-platform, notifications, push

I am only able to push Simple Text Only but not able to send URL to Open in Browser Parse Push Notification.

Comment: You can simply push the URL as simple text. Then, when the device receives this, convert it into a URL, and launch it with a web browser intent. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
```